# Scala Jackson/Jerkson deserialize a complex boolean query (AST)?

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson, boolean-expression

I'm working with a rather complex use case with Boolean Queries. In this particular case, I need to be able to store JSON in Scala classes to help make queries throughout several APIs. It's rather easy to create sophisticated JSON structures for these queries, but structuring them into Jackson-friendly classes has been a little challenging. (Seems non-trivial in a type-safe language)

Here's a JSON sample:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "or": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "tz": "America/Vancouver"
                    }
                }, {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "gender": "female"
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term": {
                                "age": 30
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

You can see above there are nested operators. So building something to model this is rather tricky. Is there a repo that has already solved this problem? Does anyone have a simple solution?

```
case class Condition(
  @(JsonProperty@field)("and")
  val and: Option[List[FormulaCondition]],

  @(JsonProperty@field)("or")
  val or: Option[List[FormulaCondition]],

  @(JsonProperty@field)("field")
  val field: Option[String],

  @(JsonProperty@field)("comparison")
  val comparison: Option[String],

  @(JsonProperty@field)("value")
  val value: Option[String]

)
```

So far I've just created a base class called `Condition` that handles all string fields, but this far from an elegant solution. If the `"term"` is an `Int` instead of a `String` this class fails. Really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: You will probably want to make your classes implement `JsonSerializable`, and make it deserializable with the `@JsonDeserialize(with = MyCustomDeserializer.class)`, the `with` of which you also have to write.

Comment: @fge yea looking at that now. looks like one of the ways to go. was also trying to see if `json4s` might help since it has Jackson support.